# Haskell: Why does this type-check?

Tags: reflection, haskell, typechecking

This is a minimal example taken from the Reflection-0.5.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-cse -fno-full-laziness -fno-float-in #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Proxy

newtype Zero = Zero Zero deriving (Show)

class ReifiesNum s where
  reflectNum :: Num a => proxy s -> a

instance ReifiesNum Zero where
  reflectNum = pure 0
```

In GHCi, I get the following:

```
>:t Zero
Zero :: Zero -> Zero
```

This makes sense: I'm asking for the type of the constructor which takes a Zero and returns a Zero.

```
>:t reflectNum
reflectNum :: (ReifiesNum s, Num a) => proxy s -> a
```

It makes sense that I could write something like

```
>let x = Just (undefined::Zero)
>reflectNum x
```

because the type Just Zero matches the type variables 'proxy s'.

Finally, the confusing part:

```
>:t (reflectNum Zero)
(reflectNum Zero) :: Num a => a
```

I do not understand how the type of the constructor Zero :: Zero -> Zero apparently matches the type variables 'proxy s', but apparently it does because the type of (reflectNum Zero) is just 'a'.

I'd appreciate help understanding this example, and links to relevant concepts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just the infix syntax of the function arrow throwing you off. First, here's an example with an easy-to-understand case: `Maybe Int`. To make it match `proxy s`, we just set:

```
proxy = Maybe
s = Int
```

Now let's pretend `a -> b` is instead written `Fun a b`, and so `Zero` has type `Fun Zero Zero` (i.e. `(Fun Zero) Zero`). To make it match `proxy s`, we set:

```
proxy = Fun Zero
s = Zero
```

In reality, `proxy` is `(->) Zero`, and so `proxy s` is `((->) Zero) Zero` ≡ `(->) Zero Zero` ≡ `Zero -> Zero`.

Comment: Why is "(->) Zero" a valid type? I can't imagine how I could write something like ">let x = [something]::((->) Zero)". I hope I'm making sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Eric `(->) Zero` isn't a valid type, it's a *type constructor*, which needs to be applied to another type to form a concrete type. The same is true of `Maybe`; there are no values of type `Maybe`, but there are values of type `Maybe Int`, `Maybe [Double]`, `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Char))`, etc. Likewise, there are no values of type `(->) Zero`, but there are values of type `(->) Zero Zero` i.e. `Zero -> Zero`.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I was missing the infix vs prefix notation, but it's clear now!